# My setState function is not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I recently tested my react native app on IOS and saw a strange bug : One of my setState call do not update my state, and i checked if everything else was correct.

I'm working on a real estate selling application. This setState was meant to, on a map, when the user click on a marker, shows a box of the estate clicked with detailled informations. So when a user click, it get the index of the estate clicked, and fill a state var currentEstate with it.

Furthemore it appears only on IOs, on Android everything is working fine, any ideas ?

Here's the code :

My toggle estate function, which contains the setState

```
  _toggleEstate(index, coords) {
    // This is what i want to put in my currentEstate, and it's not empty
    console.log(this.state.estates[index]);

    this.setState(
      {
        currentEstate: this.state.estates[index]
      },
      function() {
        // But this is empty, so the setState didn't work
        console.log(this.state.currentEstate);
      }
    );

    var newRegion = {
      latitude: coords.latitude,
      longitude: coords.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.00522,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0221
    };

    this.mapRef.animateToRegion(newRegion, 500);
  }
```

My renderEstate function which check if the currentEstate is empty and return a JSX component if not :

```
  _renderEstateItem() {
    if (this._isEmpty(this.state.currentEstate)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.estateContainer}>
          <EstateItem
            estate={this.state.currentEstate}
            displayDetailForEstate={this._displayDetailForEstate}
            showImage={false}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

And my JSX component :

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 48.8691526048,
            longitude: 2.352065575453187,
            latitudeDelta: 0.1922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421
          }}
          ref={ref => {
            this.mapRef = ref;
          }}
          onPress={() => this._clickOnMap()}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
            const coords = {
              latitude: marker.lat,
              longitude: marker.lng
            };

            return (
              <MapView.Marker
                key={index}
                coordinate={coords}
                title={this.state.estates[index].adress}
                description={
                  numeral(this.state.estates[index].price)
                    .format("0,0")
                    .replace(",", " ") + "€"
                }
                pinColor={color.electricViolet}
                onPress={() => this._toggleEstate(index, coords)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this._goToList()}
          style={
            this._isEmpty(this.state.currentEstate)
              ? styles.listButton
              : styles.listButtonUp
          }
        >
          <Image
            style={styles.listIcon}
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={require("../assets/images/purple_icons/List.png")}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        // Here it is when it's suppose to render
        {this._renderEstateItem()}


        {this._displayLoading()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And finally the constructor :

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mapRef = null;

    this.myResearch = this.props.navigation.state.params.myResearch;

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      estates: [],
      markers: [],
      currentEstate: []
    };

    Geocoder.init(constants.GOOGLE_MAPS_API);

    this._displayDetailForEstate = this._displayDetailForEstate.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: show me your constructor please.

Comment: Ok, check my answer and mark the answer and +1, if it worked.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Still the same unfortunately... The coords are used only to zoom on my map it has nothing to deal with it. Even if I do ' this.setState({currentEstate: "hello"})'  it do not work

Comment: Advice - remove all the cruft from your component until you can get a simple setState call working. When you've done that, start adding things back in slowly until it breaks again. You'll find out what went wrong by doing this.

Comment: Also just noticed that you're initial state for `currentEstate` is an array - is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've found out the solution it was just a bad click event from my code. Android and IOS has different click events priority, so the user was actually clicking on the map and not on the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `arrow functions`.

for example change

```
_toggleEstate(index, coords) {
    console.log(this.state.estates[index]);

    this.setState(
      {
        currentEstate: this.state.estates[index]
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state.currentEstate);
      }
    );
}
```

to:

```
// HERE
_toggleEstate = (index, coords) => {
    console.log(this.state.estates[index]);

    this.setState(
      {
        currentEstate: this.state.estates[index]
      },
      () => { // AND HERE
        console.log(this.state.currentEstate);
      }
    );
}
```

you must change your callbacks to arrow functions format.

Comment: Didn't work :/ still have an empty currentEstate var